# VB.Net handle PowerShell pipe?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I'm not sure how to phrase the question, but this is what I'm looking for:

I want to create a VB.Net application that can 'insert' itself in a PowerShell pipe as receiver, and *optionally* also as a producer. In other words, I want to do this:

```
Some-PowerShell-CmdLet | My-Program
```

and optionally:

```
Some-PowerShell-CmdLet | My-Program | Other-PowerShell-CmdLet
```

I would very much appreciate it if you can point out the relevant documentations and/or tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daiken/archive/2007/02/07/creating-a-windows-powershell-cmdlet-using-the-visual-studio-windows-powershell-templates.aspx) by David Aiken. It discusses getting the [Visual Studio PowerShell Templates](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/sandbox/249904-Windows-PowerShell-Visual-Studio-2005-Templates-C-and-VBNET) in C# and Vb.net and then gives a rundown on how to create a cmdlet.

You can also look at these [tutorials from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878321.aspx).

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the tips. Let me have some time reading them. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly execute the application "powershell Some-PowerShell-CmdLet | PATH/My-Program" from where Powershell will be installed.
Also use following command from Windows to start a new powershell window as:
"start powershell new-PSSession -Computername ${IPAddress} -Cred ${adminUser}\${VMUserName}"

Comment: So, IOW, I should just handle the STDOUT of the PowerShell CmdLet? Hmmm... workable... any suggestion on how to feed its output onto a CmdLet where the output will be handled as objects?